# Subject Verb Agreement and Verb Tense

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, concordancia-verbal

> > A los once años Miguel fue al campo, junto al padre y al hermano mayor. En los días más crudos del invierno **aprovecharon** para acudir a la escuela, donde **aprendieron** a leer.

What does this sentence mean?
Are my verbs correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct, but If you had said

> A los once años Miguel fue al campo, junto al padre y al hermano mayor. En los días más crudos del invierno **aprovechó** para acudir a la escuela, donde **aprendió** a leer.

would have been correct too. The difference is that in your version more than one person takes advantage of the cold days of winter to go to school, since you are using plural. In my version only Miguel is taking advantage of this fact to go to school. So what is the inflection (or your intention) here? Who went to school, just the young Miguel or his brother too?

Your tenses are correct, and I just took advantage that the first sentence talks about *Miguel*, who had to go to the field with his father and brother, to play with the number in the verb forms.